# Rails - Ajax response with rails injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to write a ajax response for a link_to button. The response includes a button which replaces the one being triggered. Everything works, except that the new button isn't replacing the old one. I've watched the railscasts episode regarding ajax and jquery, showing a `<%= j ...` at the beginning to make a rails injection js compatible. Still, something doesn't work.

The response is getting processed. If I delete the second jQuery command, the first one is executed, but with both commands inside, not even the first is executed.

Here is the `response.js.erb`

```
$('#spanID').hide().after('<span>text</span>');

$('#buttonID').hide().after('<%= j link_to "Button text", course_enrolment_path(@course, user: user),
                                  data: { confirm: "confirmation text" },
                                  method: "put", remote: true %>');
```

Thank you very much!

**Update**
Ok, I've found a hint in the terminal. The `user` variable couldn't be loaded... Is there a way to pass the `format.js { render :action => 'response_file.js.erb'}` a variable? It doesn't seem to grab the variables from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found out. The controller variables weren't loading because, of course, the .js.erb file wasn't named like the update method. I just had to extra preload the variables from the controller presenting the original view, containing the variables for the buttons.